# Using iOS6+ SDK while keeping compatibility with iOS4

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

I am trying to include a Facebook functionalty in my app, the Facebook SDK requires iOS 6 or above, according to the documentation... I also want my app to be compatible with iOS 4.

What I want to do, is to determine the iOS version at runtime and enable/disable Facebook functionnalty accordingly. Would such approach be possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know this is a limitation in the platform. the thing you can do is creating 2 apps targetting the platforms. This solution is also used by spotify.